# Non standard evaluation of date condition with filter function

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I'm trying to use `dplyr::filter()` with NSE, but I can't make it work when the filtered variable is `as.Date()`.

Here the function that almost works:

```
foo <- function(d, f, var) {
  d %>% 
    filter_(paste0(var, ">=", f))
}

d <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1)
foo(d, f=5, var="a")
#    a b
# 1  5 1
# 2  6 1
# 3  7 1
# 4  8 1
# 5  9 1
# 6 10 1
```

But if `a` is a date it won't work:

```
d <- data.frame(a=seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length.out = 7, by="day"), b=1)

foo(d, f=as.Date("2019-01-05"), var="a") # or foo(d, f="2019-01-05", var="a")
#            a b
# 1 2019-01-01 1
# 2 2019-01-02 1
# 3 2019-01-03 1
# 4 2019-01-04 1
# 5 2019-01-05 1
# 6 2019-01-06 1
# 7 2019-01-07 1
```

Also I've tried with this:

```
foo2 <- function(d, f, var) {
  d %>% 
    filter(!!var >= f)
}
#foo2(d, f=5, var="a")
#foo2(d, f="2019-01-05", var="a")
```

Which doensn't work in neither cases, I'm interested in knowing also why `foo2` it's not working.

Comment: Since you are passing the variable name as a string, you'll want something like `ensym()` around `var` in your function.  Like `var = ensym(var)` before the `filter()` line.  Then things should work for dates if you pass `f` a value via `as.Date()`.

Comment: Thank you, this works with `foo2`, care to post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `!!` (`rlang::`). Enclose `var` into `as.name` (or `as.symbol`) to make into a symbol and then use `eval()` inside `filter` to evaluate the object at the function environment:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)    

d <- data.frame(a=seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length.out = 7, by="day"), b=1)

foo2 <- function(d, f, var) {
  sym <- as.name(var)

  d %>% 
    filter(eval(sym) >= f)
}
```

Result:

```
> foo2(d, f="2019-01-05", var="a")
           a b
1 2019-01-05 1
2 2019-01-06 1
3 2019-01-07 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try to pass the `var` argument not as a string. in that case you need to change the function `foo` to:

```
foo <- function(d, f, var) {
   var <- enquo(var)
   d %>% 
      filter(!!var >= f)
}
foo(d, f=as.Date("2019-01-05"), var=a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't revise your function. Let's focus on the code

```
foo(d, f = as.Date("2019-01-05"), var = "a")
```

If the input `f` is a `Date`, the statement `paste0(var, ">=", f)` in your function will return

**`"a >= 2019-01-05"`**(It means the column `a` is greater than and equal to **`"2019-01-05"`**, which is a character string, not a Date because the outputs of `paste()` are always characters)

The statement above is not meaningful because character strings are unable to be compared. So you need to transform the Date of input to numeric by `unclass()` or `as.numeric()` such as

```
foo(d, f = unclass(as.Date("2019-01-05")), var = "a")
```

and the statement will return **`"a >= 17901"`**, which is a normal logical statement.

---

**Output**

```
foo(d, f = unclass(as.Date("2019-01-05")), var = "a")

#            a b
# 1 2019-01-05 1
# 2 2019-01-06 1
# 3 2019-01-07 1
```

Notice that **"a >= 17901"** will succeed because Dates(Column `a`) can be compared with numerics(`17910`).